# Corrupted visual during scroll - flash cs3 as2.0

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-2

My Flash CS3, ActionScript 2.0 [poker game on Facebook](http://apps.facebook.com/turn_poker/) has strange visual corruption. In the game, when you make an action (like scrolling the list in the attached screenshot), black blocks occur on the screen. In the game screen, when time has passed, again some black blocks appear. Actually, when some events happen (dealing cards animation), black areas appear.

(Black is my background colour and I am using param `name="wmode" value="transparent"` to embed Flash in HTML. I update flash player at 8 computers but this situation still resuming at 6 pc.

I couldn't find the reason or anything related with my problem.

Screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/4jeofdvg5